# Forces on object hung by two ropes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

[image]

The rectangular object shown above is hung by two ropes at the points P and Q. As we can see, these points are far apart from each other(they are not the same point).
So,

1. How do I draw the resultant force vector if vectors of the respective points are shown in the picture?
2. Do I need to extend them until they intersect and then apply parallelogram law? If so, what is the significance of this intersection point?

Answer (score 1):

(a) *Where* on the body the forces act doesn't matter for calculating their resultant. All you need is the magnitudes and directions of the two forces. You then use the parallelogram rule or equivalent. It doesn't matter *where* you draw the parallelogram.

(b) Where the lines of action of the two forces intersect (point O, say) is the point about which neither of the forces has a turning moment (torque).

(c) If the picture is uniform, the pull the Earth on it behaves like a single force (weight) acting on it downwards through its geometric centre.

(d) One condition for the picture to be in equilibrium is that the resultant force from the ropes is equal and opposite to the picture's weight (if there are only these three forces on the picture).

(e) The other condition for the picture to be in equilibrium is that there is no resultant moment about any point. If your diagram is reasonably well drawn the picture is *not* in equilibrium because the weight has an unbalanced moment about point O.